# How do i use sockets in sailsjs version 1.4

Tags: sockets, websocket, sails.js

I am trying to use sockets in sailsjs.
I have an action which just returns the socketId

```
module.exports = async function exampleAction(req, res) {
  if (!req.isSocket) {
    console.log("not a socket req");
    return res.badRequest();
  }
  sails.sockets.getId(req);
  return res.json({ socketid: sails.sockets.getId(req) });
};
```

and in routes.js:

```
"GET /label/exampleaction": {
    action: "label/example-action",
    isSocket: true,
  },
```

I'm trying to connect to it from nuxt.js using Websocket :
 `this.connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1337/label/exampleaction");`

This gives me an error:
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1337/label/exampleaction' failed:`

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to make this controller simpler, only for tests.
Like this:

```js
async function onConnect(req, res) {
    const socketId = sails.sockets.getId(req);
    res.json(socketId);
}
```

```js
'POST /connect': { controller: 'TestController', action:'onConnect' },
```

For client part, i recommend use the sails browser library: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js

You can use it in your nuxt app, it is all javascript, no mistery.

Sails Docs have a specific section with more details: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client